# Same results for RandomWalk and Snowball sampling algorithms

Tags: sampling, random-walk

I am trying to find the best sampling algorithm to obtain a sampled graph that exhibits the same distribution compared to the original graph. The metric I am using at the moment is PageRank.

The authors in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiixK.png) find that RandomWalk performs best (but use many more criteria for the metric). In order to compare the distributions of the sampled and the original graph I am using the
Kolmogorov–Smirnov test.

However, if I use the RandomWalk and SnowBall sampler from the LittleBallOfFur Library I am obtaining the exact same p-values for both sampled graphs. I am wondering why that is. I would have expected to get results that differ. I also looped through different sample sizes (from 1-3800) to compare the generated graphs and all p values are exactly the same.

[image: p-values comparison for RandomWalk and Snowball sampler]

Questions:

1. Why are the p values always the same? Shouldn´t they be different?
2. Is it realistic to only find a sample that exhibits the same distribution as the original if the sample is ~50-55% of the size of the original? I would obviously like to have a smaller sample that still exhibits the same distribution.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiixK.png) Leskovec, J. and Faloutsos, C., 2006, August. Sampling from large graphs. In Proceedings of the 12th ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining (pp. 631-636).